# Rmarkdown - HTML file select pre-generated graphs

Tags: r, r-markdown, plotly

I have 10 locations, and for each location I have generated 4 interactive plotly graphs which are saved as HTML files.

Is it possible to create a rmarkdown with a dropdown allowing the user to select a location which will load the relevant plotly graphs?

I cannot generate the graphs on the fly, and everything must be stored in HTML files with no server side interaction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest solution as of January 2018 is to use [tabsets](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/html_document_format.html#tabbed_sections) as well as the `self_contained: true` option in the RMarkdown YAML (see [this documentation](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/html_document_format.html#document_dependencies)).

Here are a couple images to show what that would look like. At the end of this post is the RMarkdown used to generate this example.

[image]
[image]

Here's the RMarkdown used to generate this example.

````
---
title: "Example"
output:
  html_document:
    self_contained: true
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
library(magrittr)
library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)
```
# Plots by Location {.tabset}

## First Location
```{r first_location_plot}
first_plot <- iris %>% 
  filter(Species == "setosa") %>% 
  ggplot(mapping = aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width)) + 
  geom_point(color = 'blue')

ggplotly(first_plot)
```

## Second Location
```{r second_location_plot}
second_plot <- iris %>% 
  filter(Species == "virginica") %>% 
  ggplot(mapping = aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width)) + 
  geom_point(color = 'red')

ggplotly(second_plot)
```
````